# Button and Label objects not showing after running build - xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am currently learning the basics of IOS development and trying to put together a simple app which consists of 1 image view, 1 label and 1 button object. These 3 objects appear in the main storyboard, however, the button and label objects disappear after running build (see images below).

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might have to add auto layout constraints.

Comment: I think you set the image for button.Please you need to add background image for button.